# Making height of images and tables match that of divs

Tags: css

**Edit:** Consider that we'd like to show a row-table of images of airplanes, and that below that we'd like to show a row-table of images of automobiles. We'd like the height of each image to match the table and div it's in, but we let the user scroll sideways as they please to view the images that are not initially visible. **End-Edit**

Because in the CSS file `tables` are given `height: 100%;`, I'm expecting the height of the images to always match that of the div they're in. This works, just so long as the height of the div they're in is not smaller than they are. In other words, the images are happy to be enlarged, but they refuse to be reduced in size.

https://jsfiddle.net/usojgd3u/

[image: planes and automobiles]

1. Why does `height: 100%;` not do what I think it should do?
2. How can I ask images to adjust their height to the table they're in, and each table to the div it's in.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top scrolling">
    <table><tr>
            <td><img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/16692/Jarno-Single-engine-Cessna.png" /></td>
            <td><img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/19623/philrich123-A380.png" /></td>
    </tr></table>
</div>
<div class="bottom scrolling">
    <table><tr>
            <td><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/74557/rally-car.png" /></td>
            <td><img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/196201/Model-T-Ford.png" /></td>
    </tr></table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 5px dashed green;
}
.scrolling {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
    border: 4px dashed red;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    border: 4px dashed blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the [`height` of a table](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) is treated as a minimim height:

> The height of a table is given by the 'height' property for the
>   'table' or 'inline-table' element. A value of 'auto' means that the
>   height is the sum of the row heights plus any cell spacing or borders.
>   Any other value is treated as a minimum height.

To prevent the images from having an impact on the size of the cells, you should take the images out of flow:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 5px dashed green;
}
.scrolling {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
.top {
  top: 0;
  border: 4px dashed red;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  border: 4px dashed blue;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top scrolling">
  <table><tr>
    <td><img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/16692/Jarno-Single-engine-Cessna.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/19623/philrich123-A380.png" /></td>
  </tr></table>
</div>
<div class="bottom scrolling">
  <table><tr>
    <td><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/74557/rally-car.png" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/196201/Model-T-Ford.png" /></td>
  </tr></table>
</div>
```

But if you don't want to restrict your images horizontally, and tables are not needed, you can just use

```css
.scrolling {
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents line breaks */
  overflow-x: scroll; /* Horizontal scrollbar */
}
.scrolling > img {
  max-height: 100%; /* Shrink if too tall */
  vertical-align: middle; /* Prevents space below the image */
}
```

```css
.scrolling {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px dashed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.top {
  top: 0;
  border-color: red;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  border-color: blue;
}
.scrolling > img {
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="top scrolling">
  <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/16692/Jarno-Single-engine-Cessna.png" />
  <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/19623/philrich123-A380.png" />
</div>
<div class="bottom scrolling">
  <img src="http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/74557/rally-car.png" />
  <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/196201/Model-T-Ford.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is really cool, but it's not quite what I'm after. Sorry about the ambiguity. I've now edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Calaf Do you mean images should not shrink by horizontal constraints? Then it's problematic because you can't take the image out-of-flow, so that they can make the cells grow. I don't think it's possible to ensure it will work with tables because there are a lot of implementation defined things. But why are you using tables anyway?

Comment: If tables are problematic, I'll happily use just divs, or any other mechanism. My attempt with an image container div that just has `float: left` is not working any better https://jsfiddle.net/usojgd3u/2/   . Suggestions welcome!

Comment: @Calaf There is no need to place images in wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

If I got this right and you want to make images fit into div; You need to set `max-width:100%` for the `img`

[Check updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usojgd3u/1/)

```
td img{
  max-width:100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Your 100% apply to the table not the table-cells (`td` elements), but your images are inside the table-cells.

2.) Concerning height: There is always the problem of proportion height to width. But try to add

```
td img{
  height:100%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This should make each image full height of the table-cell it's in, and if the cell and image proportions happen to be in a relation that the image now becomes wider than the cell, the image is centered. (altough if there are no set widths for the cells this might not happen - always depending on the actual situation)